# /me/feed/ does not provide wall posts

Tags: facebook

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api("/me/feed/", 'GET');
echo $user_profile;
```

The result is something else

Example: "A and B are now friends" and "A like .." etc. While these are not my wall posts.

Comment: This should work. Try posting something in wall and test again.

Comment: Not working...I test it many times.Results of printing user_profile  are shown in above example

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the `read_stream` permission? If you ask for the correct permission, you will be able to see all the posts to your feed (subject to privacy settings).